# How can I force mathematica to calculate the integral and print the parametric result?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have the following code:

```
substitute = {x_ Conjugate[x_] -> Abs[x]^2};

S = Sqrt[2]/2*{{1 + Conjugate[δ], 0}, {0, 1 - Conjugate[δ]}}; 

k = (1/Sqrt[2])*{{S[[1, 1]] + S[[2, 2]]}, {S[[1, 1]] - S[[2, 2]]}, {2 S[[1, 2]]}} //
     Simplify;

T0 = Dot[k, ConjugateTranspose[k]];

R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}};

T[ψ_] := Dot[R[ψ], T0, Refine[ConjugateTranspose[R[ψ]], ψ ∈ Reals]] /. substitute;

p[x_, mu_, k_] := 2*PDF[VonMisesDistribution[2 mu, k], 2 x] // Simplify;

TvolNRS = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

TvolNRS[[1, 1]] = Integrate[p[ψ, μ, κ]*T[ψ][[1, 1]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
  Assumptions -> -Pi/2 <= μ <= Pi/2] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

How can I force mathematica to calculate the highlighted integral and print the result explicitly as (a rather simple) function of the parameters $\mu$ and $\kappa$?

Comment: You seem to have got the result. What do you mean by "print"?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I mean to calculate the result of the integral and print it explicitly

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have edited my question and added the codes that are necessary for running

Comment: Your integral after removing constant parameters comes down to `Integrate[E^Cos[x], x]`, which returns unevaluated, indicating that *Mathematica* does not know how to find the antiderivative.  Do you know if there is one in terms of standard functions?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Do you know if there is one in terms of standard functions?` I don't understand what you mean by this sentence?

Comment: Do you know a formula for the antiderivative?

Comment: @MichaelE2 well [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^cosx&lk=4) says: `There is no result in terms of standard mathematical functions` So you mean the integral does not have an analytic solution so if someone wants to calculate it, they should provide numerical solutions with known $\kappa$ and $\mu$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Unless somebody knows a symbolic solution....

Comment: `Integrate[E^Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}]` is `Pi*BesselI[0,1]`. Perhaps there are some substitutions you can do to get the integrand in this form? I'm willing to bet that the integral reduces *exactly* to `Pi*BesselI[0,kappa]`, canceling out the factor in the denominator. I played around with substitutions, and it seemed to work.

Comment: @march there is a [formula](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IRRVJ.png) about bessel functions here in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) substituting $\alpha=0$ and $x=1$ will give us your result but then it's not a symbolic solution!!

Answer (score 3):

Doing symbolic manipulations with `Integrate` isn't really possible so I'll just talk this out.

```
integrand = p[ψ, μ, κ]*T[ψ][[1, 1]];
Reduce[integrand[[1, 1, 2]], ψ][[2]]
(* 1/2 (-π + 2 μ) <= ψ <= 1/2 (π + 2 μ) *)
```

This suggests that we shift the integration variable by `μ`:

```
integrand = MapAt[Reduce[#, y] &, integrand /. ψ -> μ + y // Simplify, {1, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

This shifts the limits of integration to

```
# - μ & /@ {ψ, -π/2, π/2} /. ψ -> μ + y
(* {y, -(π/2) - μ, π/2 - μ}  *)
```

However, due to the constraints on `y` from the definition of the integrand, the actual limits are given by

```
{y, Max[-(π/2), -(π/2) - μ], Min[π/2, π/2 - μ]}
```

Visualizing the integration region for different choices of `μ`:

[image]

---

So, the problem has been mapped onto the following:

```
g[μ_ /; -π/2 <= μ <= π/2] := Integrate[integrand, {y, Max[-(π/2), -(π/2) - μ], Min[π/2, π/2 - μ]}]
```

At `μ == 0`, of course, the integral evaluates to 1, since

```
Integrate[Exp[κ Cos[2 y]], {y, -π/2, π/2}]
(* π BesselI[0, κ] *)
```

I know of no closed-form analytic solution for the integral. Interestingly enough, however, certain values work:

```
g[π/4] // Expand
(* 3/4 + StruveL[0, κ]/(4 BesselI[0, κ]) *)
```

The `StruveL` function shows up, which I've actually used before.

---

This all suggests that you have to do things numerically. The integral has been made simpler, so perhaps this was a help.